# Strange behaviour of tableView's background when swiping back in a ViewController using UIVisualEffectView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I use UIVisualEffectView as my tableview's backgroundView, just for the blur effect, everything is fine except when I begin to swipe the current view back to previous view, the tableview's background immediately become black, not blurred anymore.

Comment: Is the tableview the root view of the hierarchy? How are you presenting / dismissing the view? Are you using a custom animation?

Comment: there is an UIImageView behind the tableView, I set the tableview's backgroundView to UIVisualEffectView for seeing the blurred image, and the viewController is being pushed, and no custom animation.

Answer (score 0):

UIVisualEffectView is actually  a hack in the Apple framework. It's not an overlapping layer, it completely replaces the layers behind itself by processing them. Try  to add this effect behind the table and clear background of table view.
In **viewDidLoad** method

```
self.tabelView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```